# angular-swiper not showing up in ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using angular-swiper in ionic according to [this](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-create-elegant-slider-carousel-in-ionic-framework/)

But nothing shows up on the page.
My code looks like:

swiper.html:

```
<ks-swiper-container initial-slide="3" speed="2000" loop="true" show-nav-buttons="false" slides-per-view="3" space-between="5" pagination-clickable="false" override-parameters="{effect: 'coverflow',coverflow: {rotate: 50,stretch: 0,depth: 100,modifier: 1,slideShadows : false}}"  on-ready="onReadySwiper(swiper)">
    <ks-swiper-slide class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="s in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">
        <img ng-src="img/puppy.jpg" width="100%">
    </ks-swiper-slide>            
</ks-swiper-container>
```

controller.js:

```
$scope.swiper = {};
$scope.onReadySwiper = function(swiper) {
    console.log("swiper ready");
}
```

Here onReadySwiper function is called and even it loads in the DOM but shows nothing on the screen.
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: See the complete example at [link] (http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-create-elegant-slider-carousel-in-ionic-framework/2/)

Comment: You need to post in a code block in the question itself. links are not sufficient since they could break if the site gets removed later on or if the site goes down temporarily. This won't help us answer the question if that ever becomes the case and if someone else has the same problem as you later on, they won't be able to get the same help you did.